Clarification about solvability of Dirichlet problem at infinity on a pinched negative curvature space
Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold of pinched negative curvature $(-a^2 \leq K \leq -b^2 < 0)$. Let $M_\infty$ denote the ideal boundary and $\varphi \in C^0(M_\infty)$ be a prescribed "boundary value" function. We consider the Dirichlet problem $\Delta u = 0$ on $M$, $u = \varphi$ on $M_\infty$. As far as I know, there are at least three different approaches to this, due to Anderson, Sullivan, and a third approach outlined on p. 37–40 of Schoen–Yau's book. My question is about the last, particularly about the application of Perron's method.
On p. 40, they state that $\overline{\varphi} - \alpha g$ and $\overline{\varphi} + \alpha g$ are suitable barrier functions (the functions $\varphi$ and $g$ are defined at the bottom of p. 38 and top of p.  40 respectively), which guarantee the existence of a harmonic $u$ satisfying $\overline{\varphi} - \alpha g \leq u \leq \overline{\varphi} + \alpha g$. It is immediate from previous estimates that $u$ satisfies the boundary condition $\varphi$.
My understanding of Perron's method (which is mainly based on the treatment in Section 3.2 of Jost's book) is that the harmonic function $u$ is constructed as the supremum of all subharmonic functions that are dominated by $\varphi$ on the boundary. Wherever the boundary is regular, i.e., if there is a barrier function for a point $\xi \in M_\infty$, then we have the boundary convergence at $\xi$. A barrier function by definition needs to be superharmonic and positive on $\overline{M} \setminus \{\xi\}$ and $0$ at $\xi$. As per this definition, I am not sure how $\overline{\varphi} \pm \alpha g$ are barrier functions. So I am a bit confused about the end of Schoen–Yau's proof as it does not exactly fit with the Perron's method I am familiar with. Appreciate any advice!
